# Circular dependencies in Titanium/ RequireJs

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have some circular dependencies in my Titanium application like so:

### index.js

```
var Auth = require('Auth')
```

### Auth.js

```
var PopUp = require('PopUp');

function isLoggedIn() {
    // some logic e.g. return userName !== null
};

function authorise() {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return PopUp.authorise();
    }
}
```

### PopUp

```
var Auth = require("Auth");

function authorise() {
    // some code asking user to login
}


function showSecurePopUp() {
   if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
       // show secure pop up
   }
}
```

As you can see we have a circular dependency. `Auth` needs `PopUp` and `PopUp` needs `Auth`.

This creates a circular dependency and thus the following error message:

```
[ERROR] [iphone, 10.3.3, 192.168.0.64]
Type: RangeError
Message: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
File: /iphone/Auth.js.js
Line: 24
```

How can I solve the issue of circular dependencies in a Titanium Alloy app?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the way, you do the following changes in you project and this should solve the problem.

## Alloy.js

```
var Auth = require("Auth");
var PopUp = require('PopUp');
```

## Index.js

```
Auth.authorise();
```

## Auth.js

```
var isLoggedIn = function() {
    // some logic e.g. return userName !== null
    Ti.API.info('isLoggedIn');
    return false;
};

exports.authorise = function() {
    if (isLoggedIn()) {
        Ti.API.info('authorize isloggedIn');
        return true;
    } else {
        Ti.API.info('authorize not logged In');
        return PopUp.authorise();
    }
};

exports.isLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
```

## PopUp.js

```
exports.authorise =function () {
    // some code asking user to login
    Ti.API.info('authorize funcition popup ' + Auth.isLoggedIn());
};


function showSecurePopUp() {
   if (Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
       // show secure pop up
       Ti.API.info('isLoggedIn show secure popup');
   }
}
```

Let me know if this works fine and if this is what you wanted. Also if you have some other approach that solves the problem, then let me know that also.

**Good Luck & Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian

Comment: I don't think variables in Alloy.js is accessable in other files or supposed to be accessable.

Comment: @YahyaUddin : I have tested this code and it works for me, also their is no restriction for usage of alloy.js. Only thing we need to remember is the memory usage. To much of global variables will cost a lot of memory.